not able to initiate spark session in conda windows
I am not able to initiate a spark session in my windows conda virtual python environment. However, i was able to execute this statement successfully few days back without any issue post installing the latest java version in my local drive and saving the path in my system environment variable.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("survival").getOrCreate()

When executing the code today. I am getting the below error.
Py4JJavaError Traceback (most recent call last)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getSubject is supported only if a security manager is allowed
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.getSubject(Subject.java:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:577)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1(Utils.scala:2416)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2416)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:501)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:485)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1575)


Check the Spark and Java versions. Some features may have been deprecated in newer Java version.
Here is the compatibility matrix- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Spark-and-Java-versions-Supportability-Matrix/ta-p/383669
